# Regex to replace all instances of character with consecutive numbers?

Tags: regex

I want to somehow automatically number a list of terms in a large (~50 pages) text.

All the terms that need to be numbered already have a unique string in front of them which makes finding all instances of them easy enough.

But is there some kind of regex expression I could use to "replace" them with a consecutive number and then the term again? The second part can be done with $ but I'm stuck about the first part.

For example...

**What I have:**

> This is some ^text and I ^want to modify it in a ^certain way.

**What I want:**

> This is some [1]text and I [2]want to modify it in a [3]certain way.

Comment: This  is only possible with a programming language (unless you are using Funduc S&R tool or other proprietary tools), what is yours?

Answer (score 0):

Using python, you can use replacement function for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern.
with the help of partial functions, it could be done like this:

```
import re
from functools import partial
def count(i,match):
  i[0] +=1
  return f'[{i[0]}]'
text='This is some ^text and I ^want to modify it in a ^certain way.'
re.sub(r'\^',partial(count,[0]),text)
```

And the result:

```
This is some [1]text and I [2]want to modify it in a [3]certain way.
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/bHAXI4)